I have this program which im trying to work with a json and see what talents are available, but when I try to run talents i get a error when importing
Main.py
from pygame import *
import pygame
from Talent_List import *
import requests
import json
import sys
import time


class DeepwokenBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active = True

    def start(self):
        while self.active:
            print(" Starting... welcome to the deepwoken talent checker! \n")
            self.questions()

            q = input("Would you like to continue? ")

            if q == "yes " or q == "y":
                continue

            else:
                print(" Goodbye, ending loop")
                self.active = False
                break

    def talent_reqs(self):
        pass


    def questions(self):
        flame = input("How much flamecharm do you have?\n")
        gale = input("How much galebreath do you have?\n")
        frost = input("How much frostdraw do you have?\n")
        thunder = input('How much thunder do you have?\n')

        attributes = [flame, gale, frost, thunder]

        return attributes

        def controller(self):
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Db = DeepwokenBuilder()
    Db.start()

Talents.py
import json
from Main import DeepwokenBuilder


# make talent logic here ig

with open(r'C:\Users\Zahir\Desktop\DeepwokenBuilder\Deepwoken Builder\Talent_list.json') as f:
    Talent_list = json.load(f)


class Talents:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Talent_list = Talent_list
        self.flamecharm = Talent_list['flamecharm']
        self.galebreath = Talent_list['galebreath']
        self.frostdraw = Talent_list['frostdraw']
        self.thundercall = Talent_list['thundercall']
        self.base = Talent_list['base']


    def display_talents(self):
        db = DeepwokenBuilder()

        attributes = db.questions()
        print(attributes)

        for i, v in self.Talent_list.items():
            attunement = i
            for i, v in v.items():
                talent_name = i
                talent_req = v

                print(f"{talent_name, talent_req}, {attunement} ")
                print(attributes)

                # if attributes < whatever

tt = Talents()
tt.display_talents()

Error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'DeepwokenBuilder' from partially initialized module 'Main' (most likely due to a circular import) (DeepwokenBuilder\Deepwoken Builder\Main.py)
I'm trying to figure out why I'm having the error.

Like the error message tells you, you can't have Main import Talents and Talents import Main. (It's not clear from your code that this is happening, but the error message spells it out loud and clear.) The straightforward fix is to put the shared dependency in a third file which you can import from both without a circular dependency.

(Separately, the code at the end of Talents.py will be executed at the time you import the file, which you probably don't want. Either defer this to the caller entirely, or put it in a function which the caller can invoke when they want this to happen.)

OT: You import a lot of modules that aren't needed in your program. Why? There are also other problems you will learn about once you fix the circular import.

I have the imported modules there because im still planning to use them.. havent gotten to them  yet

As a rule of thumb, don't do things you don't need to do. Don't add complexity or extra code or features because you might need them in the future. Add what you need right now, and leave future modules, code, etc. to the future when you implement them. The simpler your code is, the easier it will be to maintain and debug and, in the future, expand on it.

maybe don't use db = DeepwokenBuilder() in def display_talents(self): but send it as paramater def display_talents(self, db): - this way you don't have to use from Main import DeepwokenBuilder in Talents.py. And don't run tt = Talents() tt.display_talents() in Tallents.py but run it in Main.py with parameters tt = Talents(db)

in current code you create two instances of DeepwokenBuilder() - and this can be wrong idea because when you set something in one instance then you don't get it in other instance. You should create only one db = DeepwokenBuilder() and send it as parameter in Talent(db) or in display_talents(db). But you have to do it after creating DeepwokenBuilder() - so you can't run tt = Talents() directly in Talents.py but in Main.py you have to do from Talents import Talents and tt = Talents(db)

You have problem with import because you have real problem in your logic:

You create two instances of DeepwokenBuilder(), and when you change something in one instance then other will not have it. You should create only one DeepwokenBuilder() and send it as parameter to other class - as Talents(db) or tt.display_talents(db)
You have to create Talents() in Main.py after you create DeepwokenBuilder

    db = DeepwokenBuilder()
    tt = Talents()
    tt.display_talents(db)
    db.start()

If you change it then you don't have to import DeepwokenBuilder in Talents.py and this resolves problem with partially initialized module

Full working example.
(PEP8: lower_case_name.py for files)
(PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code)
talents.py
import json
import os

class Talents:

    def __init__(self):

        #self.path = r'C:\Users\Zahir\Desktop\DeepwokenBuilder\Deepwoken Builder\Talent_list.json'
        self.base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))        
        self.path = os.path.join(self.base_dir, 'Talent_list.json')
        
        #print('[DEBUG] Talents: self.path:', self.path)
        
        with open(self.path) as f:
            self.data = json.load(f)
            
        self.flamecharm = self.data['flamecharm']
        self.galebreath = self.data['galebreath']
        self.frostdraw = self.data['frostdraw']
        self.thundercall = self.data['thundercall']
        self.base = self.data['base']

    def display_talents(self, db):

        attributes = db.questions()
        print(attributes)

        for attunement, value in self.data.items():
            for talent_name, talent_req in value.items():
                print(f"{talent_name, talent_req}, {attunement} ")
                print(attributes)

                # if attributes < whatever

main.py
#import pygame   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from talents import Talents  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for files with code - `talents.py` 

class DeepwokenBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active = True

    def start(self):
        while self.active:
            print(" Starting... welcome to the deepwoken talent checker! \n")
            self.questions()

            q = input("Would you like to continue? ")
            q = q.strip().lower()
            
            #if q !== "yes" and q != "y":
            if q not in ("yes", "y"):
                print(" Goodbye, ending loop")
                self.active = False
                break

    def questions(self):
        flame = input("How much flamecharm do you have?\n")
        gale = input("How much galebreath do you have?\n")
        frost = input("How much frostdraw do you have?\n")
        thunder = input('How much thunder do you have?\n')

        self.attributes = [flame, gale, frost, thunder]

        return self.attributes


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = DeepwokenBuilder()   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
    tt = Talents()
    tt.display_talents(db)
    db.start()

example Talent_list.json if someone would like to test it
{
"flamecharm": {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3},
"galebreath": {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3},
"frostdraw": {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3},
"thundercall": {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3},
"base": {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}
}

